# How do I clear memory of file's data while the program that runs it is still running

Tags: c, file, memory, fopen, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a program that is supposed to detect if the same memory data is already loaded into memory by recording the write time of data put into memory.

How it works: [KSM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/KSM) (tool of Linux) saves memory by using the same memory location for duplicated copies of data to save some memory. When this data gets written after it has been combined with a copy, the two data segments must split back up again because they would become different. This is essentially creating a new copy, then writing to it. This process of creating a new copy then writing to it takes significantly longer to write to as opposed to writing to memory that is not combined. This write time is recorded, and thus shows if there is another data source within memory that matches what I am writing to.

Problem: I cannot find out how to dump a file from memory after I open it. I have tried the file descriptor method of opening a file with `open()` and then closing it with `clone()` (`close()`?) as well as currently using `fopen()` and `fclose()`. I have a program that runs in the host environment and uploads the file to memory, then later writes to it to detect KSM file merging. I have a virtual environment that runs its own program that just opens the file, essentially uploading it to memory just by opening it. These programs will both upload the file to memory at the same time, then writing to the memory location the file is uploaded to with show if they have merged based on the write time. The thing is, just running the program in the host environment, I am detecting KSM-merging. I have narrowed it down to most likely being the file itself still being in memory after I open it and combining with a copy of the file made in the program. Unfortunately there is no way around making a copy of the file that I know of. I need to used a certain function, `madvise()`, in order to upload from host environment to work with KSM tool. Can someone help me with a for sure way to remove the file from memory?

As mentioned, I have tried to used file descriptor method of opening a file, with `open()` and `close()`. I am currently running `fopen()` and `fclose()`. I have set the pointer of the file to NULL after calling `fclose()` as well. I am uploading an `.mp3` file. When calling `memset()`, then value uploaded is the byte itself. I have added 7 to value, for every byte upload, to see if it is the file being opened in the program. The tests show no sign of duplication when I do this. It proves that the KSM-duplication that is being detected is isolated from the program. I have also created a byte array of the file, then reversed the order of the bytes, then uploaded to memory, in order to get rid of the possibility of the array containing the bytes to be merging with the upload. Here is my code...

```
//
// Created by Taylor on 8/2/2019.
//

//#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

  if(argc < 2){
    printf("Must input a file name after running program.\n\nExample: [User@somewhere] ./RunProg <filename>\n");
  }


//    int fd;
//    struct stat statbuf;
//
//    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP);
//    if (fd == -1)
//    {
//        printf("failed to open %s\n", argv[1]);
//        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//    }
//
//    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) == -1)
//    {
//        printf("failed to fstat %s\n", argv[1]);
//        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//    }

    /*Thank you, user1274193, from stackoverflow.com*/


//    long filesize = fileSize(argv[1]);
//    char *byteArray = fileByteArray(argv[1]);


    FILE *fileptr;
    char *byteArrayx;
    long filesize;

    fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");  // Open the file in binary mode
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);          // Jump to the end of the file
    filesize = ftell(fileptr);             // Get the current byte offset in the file
    rewind(fileptr);                      // Jump back to the beginning of the file
    printf("\n\nfilesize: %d \n\n", filesize);

    byteArrayx = (char *)malloc((filesize)*sizeof(char)); // Enough memory for file + \0
    fread(byteArrayx, filesize, 1, fileptr); // Read in the entire file
    printf("First 10 bytes of file: ");
    for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
        printf(" %d ", (unsigned) byteArrayx[z]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    char *byteArray = (char *)malloc((filesize)*sizeof(char));


    //Array created so byteArray does not combine with page_1 array
    //reversed order ensures no combination.
    int ref = 0;
    for (int y = filesize; y > 0; y--){
        byteArray[ref] = byteArrayx[y-1];
        ref++;
    }
    fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
    fileptr = NULL;
    for (int z = 0; z < filesize; z++){
        byteArrayx[z] = 0;
    }
    free(byteArrayx);


    struct timespec start, end;
    long lSize;
    //int filesize = statbuf.st_size;

    size_t p_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    int pagesize = p_size;
    int pages;
    long writeDur;
    char c;
    void **pages_1 = (void **)calloc( pages, sizeof(void *));
    printf("\nFile size: %d bytes\n", filesize);
    printf("\nPage size: %d bytes\n", pagesize);
    if ((filesize/pagesize * pagesize) < filesize){
        pages = filesize/pagesize + 1;
    }
    else pages = filesize/pagesize;

    printf("\nNumber of pages: %d\n", pages);

//    char *byteArray = malloc(filesize);
//
//    for(int i = 0; i < filesize; i++){
//        read(fd, &c, 1);
//        byteArray[i] = c;
//    }

    //debugging purposes
    //printf("\nFinished Array\n");




    for(int i = 0; i < pages; i++){
        pages_1[i] = mmap(NULL, p_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        //printf("\nOn Page: %d\n", i);
        for(int ii = 0; ii < p_size; ii++){
            //printf("\nOn Byte: %d\n", (i*p_size)+ii);
            if (((i*p_size)+ii) < filesize ){
                memset(pages_1[i] + ii, (unsigned) (byteArray[    ((   ((i*p_size)+ii) - (filesize - 1)) * -1)     ]), 1);
                //memset(pages_1[i] + ii, 888, 1);
                printf(" %d ",  (byteArray[    ((   ((i*p_size)+ii) - (filesize - 1)) * -1)     ]));
            }
        }
        madvise(pages_1[i], p_size, MADV_MERGEABLE);
    }

    printf("\nUploaded file %s to memory....\n", argv[1]);
    for (int z = 0; z < filesize; z++){
        byteArray[z] = 0;
    }
    free(byteArray);
    //removes array so it is not in memory
    //to be combined with other pages made in pages_1
    //!!!pages_1 should be the only block representing the file in memory!!!




//    if (close(fd) == -1)
//    {
//        printf("failed to fclose %s\n", argv[1]);
//        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//    }
    printf("\n%s has finished uploading.\n", argv[1]);


    sleep(130);
    printf("An adequate amount of time for merging has passed. \n Please press enter to test. \n Please press \"q\" then enter to quit program. \n");


    char press;

    while(1){

        if (press == 0x0a){
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
            for(int i = 0; i < pages; i++){
                //printf("\nOn Page %d\n", i + 1);
                memset(pages_1[i],7,1);
            }
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
            printf("\nWrite time after upload took: %dns\n", end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
        }

        else if (press == 0x71){
            break;
        }

        press = getchar();

    }

    free(pages_1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I should not see a large number indicated combined memory after hitting enter once, yet I do. The value shown after hitting enter twice is what is to be expected after just hitting enter once.

Results:

```
Write time after upload took: 1436862ns
Write time after upload took: 51896ns
Write time after upload took: 44083ns
Write time after upload took: 18412ns
Write time after upload took: 18217ns
Write time after upload took: 38242ns
Write time after upload took: 20739ns
```

Comment: Using `else if (press == 0x71)` is a gruesome way of writing `else if (press == 'q')`.  Also, the first time you use it, the variable `press` is uninitialized — you should make sure it is initialized before you compare it with `'\n'` (not `0x0a`).  Character constants make your code clearer.

Comment: You're elapsed time calculation is not entirely robust; the nanoseconds could rollover so that the end value of `tv_nsec` is smaller than the start value.

Comment: Note that using `open()` on a file does _not_ cause it to be read from disk.  You need a read or write operation for that.

Comment: You don't show the PID of the process that's reading or writing the file.  Once you've modified the file once, it doesn't change again — you continue writing `7` (control-G) bytes (or, at least, one of your loops does that).  Your code is quite big and laden with not very relevant comments.  If I'm reading it correctly, you've only got one thumping big `main()` function — functions were invented for a purpose.

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler, thanks for all the edits. The only thing I have to add to your comments is that I have an fread function. I am going to clean up the code later. This is purely testing. I did create functions for reading in the file later, hoping that reading the file in a separate function would remove the file contents from memory, but it didn't show anything different.

Comment: and @JonathanLeffler, you're right. Sometimes the write time is a negative value, like  -961296345ns. Can you explain how this happens?

Comment: Consider two times about 1 millisecond apart — (1) `(struct timespec){ .tv_sec = 123456788, .tv_nsec = 999888777 }` and (2) `(struct timespec){ .tv_sec = 123456789, .tv_nsec = 000777666 }`.  When you subtract the `tv_nsec` value of (1) from the `tv_nsec` value of (2), you end up with a large negative value because you've not taken into account the change in the seconds value.  That's how you get the large negative value.  Fixing that is a bit harder — you need to write a function that will do the job, leaving you with a value `(struct timespec){ .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 888889 }`.

Comment: You might find some semi-relevant macros in `/usr/include/sys/time.h` for `timeradd()` and `timersub()` — they're semi-relevant because if they exist, they're for `struct timeval` rather than `struct timespec`.  They seem to originate in BSD Unix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm going to try this out...
totalTime = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * (1000000000)) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);